# Date from SQL recordset missing milliseconds; auto-formatted to US locale

Tags: asp-classic

I am using the following code to retrieve a date from a SQL database.

```
set db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
db.Open dbConnection

Set c1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set c1.ActiveConnection = db
c1.CommandType = adCmdText
c1.CommandText = "SELECT [Date] FROM SomeTable WHERE ID=?"
c1.Parameters.Append c1.CreateParameter("@ID", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ID))

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open c1, , 1, 3
```

When printing `rs("Date")`, the date is printed as `12/1/2017 2:15:07PM`.

Running the above query in the database returns this date `2017-12-01 14:15:06.675`.

My overall goal is to not receive a date, that is rounded up to the next full second. I would rather receive a date where the milliseconds are stripped off and not than rounded up. In this case: `12/1/2017 2:15:06PM`.

It would also be fine, to receive the date the same way the query returns the date: `2017-12-01 14:15:06.675`

At this point I am not sure what causes this auto-formatting of the date.

Thank you very much for your help :-)

Comment: I don't mind that this question is being down-voted, but would like to hear what I can improve in my question :-)

Comment: Agreed. I hate seeing down votes with no reason on why. Did you get a chance to try out the solution I posted?

Comment: @JoshMontgomery It can be fustrating, but it stems from peoples experience. It used to be the case that the community was more open but due to revenge down-voting people became less likely to be open and honest while voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DateDiff but the smallest unit it can return is seconds. No problem to get milliseconds from seconds though:

```
milliSecs = DateDiff("s", cdate("1970-01-01"), rs("Date")) * 1000
```

you'd probably be better off converting the column to a string and formatting the [date] column directly in sql:

```
c1.CommandText = "SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), [Date], 121) FROM SomeTable WHERE ID=?"
```

for more date formats, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I ended up stripping the right four characters (milliseconds) using `someVariable = LEFT(rs("Date"), (LEN(rs("Date"))-4))` after using your modified `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @jrn instead of doing this after as Josh suggested it can all be done in the SQL query. Simply adjust `VARCHAR(24)` in the `CONVERT` to the desired length, in this case `VARCHAR(20)` will produce the same result.

Comment: @Lankymart that’s a great suggestion. Thank you!!

Comment: "it can all be done in the SQL query" - isn't that what I was saying? not trying to be combative, just curious on if I missed something (other than the length of the field)...